# Gas Estimation errored and fail to transact

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I get the error of transacting and gas estimation errored

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import './token.sol';
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Vendor {
    address payable public admin;
    address payable private ethFunds = payable(0xF0a0c00Ac9D04d2e0eEF281607836b4AEa130eFa);
    Token public token;
    uint256 public tokensSold;
    int public tokenPriceUSD;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    uint256 public transactionCount;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    struct Transaction {
        address buyer;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Transaction) public transaction;

    constructor(Token _token) {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        tokenPriceUSD = 50;
        token = _token;
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function getETHPrice() public view returns(int) {
        (, int price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return (price / 10**8);
    }

    function facuTokenPriceInETH() public view returns(int) {
        int ethPrice = getETHPrice();
        return tokenPriceUSD / ethPrice;
    }

    function buyToken(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        //int facuTokenPriceETH = facuTokenPriceInETH();
        // Check that the buyer sends the enough ETH
        require(int(msg.value) >= tokenPriceUSD * int(_amount));
        // Check that the sale contract provides the enough ETH to make this transaction.
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount);
        // Make the transaction inside of the require
        // transfer returns a boolean value.
        require(token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount));
        // Transfer the ETH of the buyer to us
        ethFunds.transfer(msg.value);
        // Increase the amount of tokens sold
        tokensSold += _amount;
        // Increase the amount of transactions
        transaction[transactionCount] = Transaction(msg.sender, _amount);
        transactionCount++;
        // Emit the Sell event
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        // Return the tokens that were left inside of the sale contract
        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(token.transfer(admin, amount));
        selfdestruct(payable(admin));
    }

}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("CursedToken", "CT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000 * 10**18);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

When I try to call the function buytokens it creates and transaction but it fails

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Please include also 'token.sol' code. Thanks

Comment: Also included token.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received that error because the smart contract haven't token. I tried your smart contract and seen that if you don't send an amount of your tokens (CursedToken) to the smart contract's address you cannot call the buy function.
This line of code give you reverted error:

```
require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount);
```

Before you call the `buy()` function try to send an amount of your tokens (CursedToken) to smart contract's address and then try to call the `buy()` function or other function of smart contract.
To send an amount of your token to smart contract you can use Send function in metamask.

**NOTE**: Before send the token you must to import your your token with Import Tokens function in metamask.

Comment: I get the error here `require(int(msg.value) >= tokenPriceUSD * int(_amount))`

Comment: If you're having error there, I think because you don't put the value into textbox greater than the multiplication operation.